# Can't pass address of char array to another function using it as pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm new to C, so I'm probably overseeing something.
I want to pass the addresses of the 2 char arrays 'Word' and 'Word_prod' to the function Mirror, converting those addresses to the pointers 'base' and 'prod'.

```
    int basic_Mirror()
{
    int ram = 256;  //not important
    char Word[ram];
    char Word_prod[ram];


    printf("Word to be mirrored: "); //not important
    fgets(Word, ram-1, stdin);  //not important
    fflush(stdin);  //not important

    int length = strlen(&Word);  //not important


    Mirror(Word, Word_prod, length, ram);

    return 1;
}

int Mirror(char * base, char * prod, int length, int ram)
{
    for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
    {
        *prod[i] = *base[length-(2+i)];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
main.c:30:9: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   30 |         *prod[i] = *base[length-(2+i)];
      |         ^~~~~~~~
main.c:30:20: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   30 |         *prod[i] = *base[length-(2+i)];
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Really don't know what's not working right there, as far as I know 'Word' and 'Word_prod' should already represent an address and not need an '&', but adding an & also doesn't help.

Comment: You might think that `fflush(stdin);` is not important, but it's actually *undefined behavior* according to the C specification: Passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is not allowed.

Comment: The * operator is being applied to the value prod[i] -- which is an int. You can't dereference an int, so this is throwing an error.

More generally, your function is taking in an address of a char, and the [] tells the compiler to go to that address + an offset. You're essentially telling it to use your char value prod[i] as an address -- which makes no sense.

Comment: Also, `strlen(&Word)` is wrong as well. The `strlen` function expects an argument of type `char *`, but the type of `&Word` is `char (*)[256]`.

Comment: Furthermore, always declare functions before you call them. This is also rather important. Your [mre] doesn't show that, so it's not a very good [mre].

Comment: Finally for your problem, for any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. So when you do `prod[i]` you already dereference the pointer `prod`, it's built into the array indexing. No more dereferencing needed. Please refresh the chapters on pointers and arrays in your text-books.